# Get Django admin.ModelAdmin to display join of two tables

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a Django app with the following models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Order(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    delivered = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order,
                              related_name='items',
                              on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product,
                                related_name='order_items',
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

And in my admin.py, I have this

```
from django.contrib import admin

@admin.register(Order)
class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email',
                    'paid', 'delivered']
    list_filter = ['paid', 'delivered']
```

This only shows the Order table.

I would like to join the Order with the OrderItem table and display it in the Django admin. I am not sure this is relevant but for one Order, there could be many OrderItem(s).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't show `OrderItem`s in `OrderAdmin` directly. But you can show `Order` in `OrderItemAdmin`, or use [InLineModelAdmin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-options) to show OrderItems in `Order` Detail page. Like this:

```
class OrderItemInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = OrderItem

class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        OrderItemInline,
    ]
```

If you still want to display OrderItems (or parts of order item) in admin page, then you can add a method in `list_display` field, and use that method to fetch `OrderItems`. Like this:

```
class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (..., 'get_order_items')

    def get_order_items(self, obj):
        return return ", ".join(obj.items.values_list("pk", flat=True))
    get_order_items.short_description = 'Order Items'
```

Comment: I have tried the above and it's not ideal. Is there some way of exporting the joined tables into csv from the admin page?

Comment: Probably you can look into this package: https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_admin.html